# Got a org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$1: nonce must have length from 7 to 13 octets while decrypt bytes

Tags: java, encryption, aes, bouncycastle

Here is my code to decrypt some base64-encoded string (or it's bytes array, yes):

```
IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec("randombigrandom".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        bytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CCM/NOPADDING", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        ret = ByteBuffer.wrap(cipher.doFinal(Base64Utils.decode(requestBody.getEncryptedData().getBytes())));
```

I use AES/CCM, because we working with BLE (bluetooth low energy) device that uses AES/CCM by default. And i got an exception:

```
org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$1: nonce must have length from 7 to 13 octets
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineInit(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas how to set that nonce?

Comment: A nonce is similar to an IV.  Try setting the IV to a random 64 bit number and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

According to [IETF RFC 3610 -- Counter with CBC-MAC (CCM)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3610), the nonce *N* must have length *15 - L* octets, where *L* has range *2 - 8* octets. The recommended value for *L* is *8*, as the message length *l(m)* is limited by *0 <= l(m) < 2^(8L)*, so with *L = 8*, the maximum message length is *2^64 - 1*.

The value you are providing for your `IvParameterSpec` is `randombigrandom`, which is *15* bytes. Depending on the length chosen for your message, this value must be between *7* (*15 - 8*) and *13* (*15 - 2*) octets.

As you are receiving the encrypted data from an external source, the nonce should be accompanying each encrypted message (it is not necessary for the nonce to be encrypted or secret, only unique and non-predictable per message). You should populate the `IvParameterSpec` with the provided nonce upon message receipt (read the spec for your device to understand how it serializes the message -- it may be a separate field in your request body, or you may need to split the encrypted data field by byte boundaries).

**It should be stated unequivocally that you MUST use a unique nonce value for every message encrypted with the same key.** Failure to do so **destroys the security properties of this mode** (words of the authors). Using a static nonce with no counter guarantees that any messages you send will be trivially broken.